# Spring data JPA with SQL Server - lower() function causes full table scan

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

In a simple SpringBoot (2.0.5) + JPA + SQL Server microservice with persistence via a `JpaRepository` implementation (no additional methods), we are seeing the transact-sql `lower()` function being injected into the generated SQL wrapping the queried column(s), which in turn causes a **full table scan** and therefore impacts performance on what would otherwise be a simple, fast index-supported query.

Clearly this is to make the queries case-insensitive, however as SQL Server is case-insensitive by default there is no need for this function to be injected.  I can see from the Spring Data JPA docs that suffixing repository methods with `IgnoreCase` should make queries case-insensitive for DBs that are case-sensitive by default, however I can't see how to configure it to respect the incoming case..

JPA config:

```
jpa:
  show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    naming:
      physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    ddl-auto: validate
```

Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<Thing, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Thing> {}
```

I have tried removing the `SQLServer2012Dialect` from the config - no difference.  I am unsure if the additional use of QueryDSL might be having an impact - I shall try temporarily removing that (although it is required).

Comment: Which method are you calling on MyRepo? And I would also say that Querydsl is the problem. I've never seen that hibernate is adding any lower or upper function without telling so

Comment: I think you may be right, I'm going to try removing it this afternoon.  This is the method I'm calling (which is indeed from `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`: `Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: and how does the predict look like?

Comment: that was it - see answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection of the QueryDsl predicate, this was straightforward (and self-inflicted) - changed the use of `equalsIgnoreCase()` in the predicate to `eq()` and that has resolved the issue.  So no issue in config or libraries, but one to be aware of.